# Scala : How to speed up parallel synchronous processing on a small list?

Tags: scala, parallel-processing

I see that Parallel collections are mostly designed to speed up processing of large collections but it is not mentioned if this can be helpful for small lists or not.

Check this example:

```
List(1,2,3).map(loadHeavyFile(_))

List(1,2,3).par.map(loadHeavyFile(_)).toList
```

What I want to know here is that :

- Is one faster than another?
- Will Scala use multiple threads if the list only has 3 elements?
- In a general way, is it possible to speed up the response time of this code?

I know I can use Future, then `Future.sequence` and wait for the result to come up, but this seems unnatural when `loadHeavyFile` is a synchronous call. I don't want to have to specify a timeout for example.

**Note:** I want to preserve list ordering.

Any guidance here is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In [parallel collections Measuring Performance - How big should a collection be to go parallel?](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/performance.html) note some parameters that are useful for estimating and deciding whether a parallel version of a collection may outperform the non-parallel one.

For such a small list, the overhead of creating the parallel version may be larger than the actual sequential mapping; however in this example the focus lies on I/O performance and possibly on memory management, should the involved files be large and be uploaded to memory.

To provide a more factual answer, consider benchmarking the sequential and parallel versions for different I/O loads in order to estimate roughly which heavy I/O load threshold makes the parallel version worth it. The I/O factor makes the estimation OS and hardware dependent and it may prove it hard to generalise.